# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined onSVGLoad

Tags: javascript, svg

I don't know why this happens, but when I have:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 30 20"
 onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
 </svg>
```

I got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: makeDraggable is not defined
    onSVGLoad
```

but when I change it to:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 viewBox="0 0 30 20"
 onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</svg>
```

the error is gone.

**Update**
This is my full html code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Garden Tracker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button onclick="startCreatingField()">+</button>
        <button onclick="finishCreatingField()">tick</button>
    </div>
    
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     viewBox="0 0 width height" id="garden-map" onload="makeDraggable(evt)">
    <script type="text/javascript"> //THIS IS WERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
    </script>
    <polygon class="draggable" fill="#ffa500" points="169 156 174 182 150 170 126 182 131 156 112 138 138 134 150 110 162 134 188 138"/> //JUST FOR TEST
</svg>
</body>
<script src="magic.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load of magic.js comes after the browser has encountered makeDraggable.

Move the `<script>` to the `<head>` so it's loaded first.